# Error 500 while send POST-request to ebay large-merchant-service (Bulk Data Exchange API) for createUploadJob

Tags: ebay-api

Using the Ebay API I am getting a 500 error while sending a POST to `createUploadJob`.

I want to create an `UploadJob` for the Bulk Data Exchange API, but every time I receive "Net::HTTPInternalServerError 500 Internal Server Error readbody=true" back. I'm using Ruby on Rails to send this xml-requests feed to ebay:

```
< ? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

< createUploadJobRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/services">

  < uploadJobType> "AddFixedPriceItem" < /uploadJobType>

  < UUID> "ebay-upload-123456"< /UUID>

< /createUploadJobRequest>
```

Here are the headers (here as a hash, but they are added to the headers later):

```
"X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME" => "createUploadJob",
"X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME" => "BulkDataExchangeService",  
"X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-TOKEN" => AUTH_TOKEN,
```

I'm using this ebay endpoint:

```
"https://webservices.ebay.com/BulkDataExchangeService"
```

My `NET::HTTP` build:

```
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new( [uri.path, uri.query].join('?') )

  req.body = content if verb == POST and !content.nil?

  if (!headers.nil?)

    headers.each do | key, value |

      req[key] = value

    end

  else

    logger.debug "HEADER Empty!"

  end

  http.request(req)
```

The scheme is `https` and the method is `POST`. `getItem-Fkt` of the Trading API works, but for the lms I receive the above error.

-> i find something interesting in the error-logger for the responses ...
I dont understand why, in Trading API in works, maybe i have to encode it to utf-8? ...

```
[05.08.2015 17:49:00]:<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errorMessage xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/services"><error>
<errorId>11002</errorId><domain>Security</domain><severity>Error</severity>

<category>System</category><message>Authentication failed : The token does not exist, the user must complete the Auth &amp; Auth sign in process to generate token.</message>
<subdomain>Authentication</subdomain><parameter name="Param1">The token does not exist, the user must complete the Auth &amp; Auth sign in process to generate token.</parameter></error></errorMessage>
```